# "Post Code Suffix" in Reports is the same as "Postal Code"

Tags: civireport, export, postcode

I'm running CiviCRM 5.10.4 on top of Drupal 7.63 on Debian, with localisation.

My contacts have UK-style postcodes with the first half (e.g. "M19") stored in "Postal Code" and the second (e.g. "3JD") in "Post Code Suffix".

I am trying to get a list of my members, with full postcode data, as a CSV. I generate the built-in "Membership Report (Detail)" which is at `/civicrm/report/instance/20` for my instance. I then add the "Postal Code" and "Post Code Suffix" columns (among other address ones). The data displayed in "Post Code Suffix" is identical to that in "Postal Code", e.g. they are both "M19". This is also the case in an exported CSV of the report.

The correct data is in the database - clicking on any "Contact Name" from the report takes me to the individual "View Contact" screen, where the Post Code & Suffix are correct (e.g. "M19" "3JD").

Any idea what's going on here or how I can fix this?

Comment: any reason not to have all the UK postcode in the postcode field? It is how i have seen many sites use it that way. I thought the suffix thing was more for US postcodes

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered a bug in the Membership Details report.

The first step in a situation like this is to see whether anyone else has reported the issue on the [CiviCRM issue tracker](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=postal+code). A link to the issue tracker is at the bottom of every CiviCRM screen.

As of this posting, it doesn't look like anyone has created an issue, so you can [write one up](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/new). You could pretty much paste in the description you've written in your question here.

To actually get the bug fixed, you may need to engage a [CiviCRM service provider](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).

In the meantime, if you just need to export a CSV of your members' contact information, including postal codes, try using Search > Find Memberships, and in the search results choose the "Export Members" action.